# Would XAML resources & threading help WPF performance in a 'game of life' scenario?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation, graphics, thread-safety

Geometries seem to be the way to go with a WPF & VB "Game of Life". But the problem is that WPF seems to have performance issues with parer numbers of objects. One appealing thing I read (below) about Geometries is that they can utilize WPF "resources".

That made me wonder if using a XAML *resource* as a class (to make *instances* of) were possible.

In my game, there would be just a few 'types' of 'beings' for game of life. I imagine being able to run a background thread for each type (3 or 4), and using a resource as a template/class to make them. So, define 3-4 resources (squares, ellipses), and use code behind for logic/animation.

I imagine an array of lifeform objects (one for each type), then cycle through them.

Are there any major flaws with this logic?

*In MS Documentation:*

> Freezable Features
>
> Because it inherits from the Freezable class, the Geometry class
>   provide several special features: Geometry objects can be declared as
>   XAML Resources, shared among multiple objects, made read-only to
>   improve performance, cloned, and made thread-safe. For more
>   information about the different features provided by Freezable
>   objects, see the Freezable Objects Overview.

Any input appreciated!

Comment: Just try the simplest thing that works (I'd start by just running it all on the UI thread - it should be fine!), and if performance is an issue, then talk about the specific issue. There are too many variables to answer your question without an exhaustive dissertation. Do something, and then you can answer the question "what have you tried" when you have a concrete issue.

Comment: Thank you! (minimum character requirement for comment)